# All training set at once or line by line

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am building simple logistic regression on python.
My training set looks like this:

`X = [[2,3],[6,5],...]`

`y = [[1],[0],[0],...]`

When I train my set, I feed one by one `x(i)` for `y(i)` and calculate their loss.

As you can expect my for-loop goes by `x`'s length (rows count = `m`).

It seems ok. But when I tried to feed the whole set at once my loss improved. My for-loop then goes by any number I chose.

Why is this? I thought it was row by row calculation for logistic regression.

edit(this is my old code.As you can see i am feeding row by row.)

```
dataset = np.loadtxt(".\logisticdata.txt",dtype=np.float32,delimiter=",")


x = dataset[:,(0,1)]
y = dataset[:,2]

x = x.reshape((100,2))
y = y.reshape((100,1))


class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        self.n11 = torch.nn.Linear(2,1)
        self.sgn = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

        """
        self.sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
        self.n21 = torch.nn.Linear(1,1)
"""
    def forward(self, *input):
        out = self.n11(*input)
        out = self.sgn(out)
        """
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        out = self.n21(out)
"""
        return out

net = Net()

criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(),lr=0.001)


for epoch in range(100):
    for xi,yi in zip(x,y):

        xi = Variable(torch.from_numpy(xi))
        yi = Variable(torch.from_numpy(yi))

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = net(xi)
        loss = criterion(output,yi)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print("Loss",loss.data[0])
```

But when i changed like this :

```
xi = Variable(torch.from_numpy(x))
yi = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y))

for epoch in range(150000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = net(xi)
    loss = criterion(output, yi)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print("Loss", loss.data[0])
```

i've got better loss.

Comment: Can you show your sample code/output that you have/got? It is quite unclear from your question what you did and what you want to do.

Comment: i am adding code line.

Comment: i've added some code.

Comment: Can you try same number of epochs in both situations and check the final loss/accuracy of the model? Definitely, the first scenario (backpropagating the error for each sample) should give better result than the second one(backpropagating error for the entire training samples). Though, it consume lot of time and memory.Number of epochs matters here